# I want the first 4 numbers of a string and keep the comma in between

Tags: php, replace

I get this output of a string:

It's in the **$Prijs** variable.

```
$Prijs = '&euro; 30,00<div class="additional">+&euro; 6,00';
```

I only want this output:

```
30,00
```

I have tried this:

```
$symbols = array('€', '&euro;');
$Prijs = str_replace($symbols, '', $Prijs);
$Prijs = substr($Prijs, 0, 4);
```

This gives me 30,006.00 as a result, I want to delete the last digits.
The $Prijs can also be a 100.00 or 1000.00 euro.

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you find yourself writing ___but it does not work___ remember, thats a poor description of a probelm. Always tell us in what way it does not work

Comment: Will the number always be only 5 characters long? Or could it be `'&euro; 1230,00<d...`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your comment, i have improved my question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It can be 6 characters or at most 7. So the maximum will be 9999.99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like in this situation a regex may be the best and safest way forward

```
$Prijs = '&euro; 9130,00<div class="additional">+&euro; 6,00';

preg_match('/([0-9,]+[^<])+/', $Prijs, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Update:

This regex feels better

```
preg_match('/\d+,\d+/', $Prijs, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

After you remove euro symbol there's still a space left over at the start of the string. So you just need to start the substring one character to the right - and also increase its length by one because `30,00` is 5 characters long, not 4:

```
$Prijs = substr($Prijs, 1, 5);
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ecc29784ab6ece5d24cdf909e35d261a167e4c4

Comment: This won't work when it's a number higher than 99.99, do you have a solution for that too?

Comment: If the length of the number is variable you'd probably have to use Regular Expressions to match it. But I've answered the question as stated. If you have a more complex scenario in reality, it would have been good to mention that at the beginning.